# node.js asynchronous logic behavior

Tags: multithreading, node.js

I am building a CPU intensive web app, where ill write the CPU intensive stuff in C++ while ill write the webserver in node.js. The node.js would be connected to c++ via addons. I am confused about one thing -

Say the time of the CPU intensive operation per request is 5 seconds(maybe this involved inverting a huge matrix). When this request comes through, the node.js binding to c++ would send this request over to the c++ code.

Now does this mean that node.js would not be caught up for the next 5 seconds and can continue serving other requests?

I am confused as i have heard that even though node offers asynchronous features, it is still single threaded.

Obviously I would not want node.js to be stuck up for 5s as it is a huge price to pay. Imagine 100s of requests simultaneously for this intensive operation..

Answer (score 2):

Trying to understand JS callbacks and asynchronicity logic, i came across with many different versions of the following description;

> a callback function which is passed to another function as a parameter, runs
>   following to the *time taking* process of the function it's passed to.

The dilemma gets originated with the "time taking" adjective. Such as is it

- Time taking because of CPU being idle and waiting for a response?
- Time taking because of CPU being busy with number crunching like hell?

This is not clear in the description and confused me. So i tried the following two codes.

```js
getData('http://fakedomain1234.com/userlist', writeData);

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += "show this before data ...";

function getData(dataURI, callback) {
    // Normally you would actually connect to a server here.
    // We're just going to simulate a 3-second delay.
    var timer = setTimeout(function () {
        var dataArray = [123, 456, 789, 012, 345, 678];
        callback(dataArray);
    }, 3000);
}

function writeData(myData) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += myData;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <p id="output"></p>
</body>
```

and

```js
getData('http://fakedomain1234.com/userlist', writeData);

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += "show this before data ...";

function getData(dataURI, callback) {
    var dataArray = [123, 456, 789, 012, 345, 678];
    for (i=0; i<1000000000; i++);
    callback(dataArray);
}

function writeData(myData) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += myData;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <p id="output"></p>
</body>
```

so in both codes there is a time taking activity in the getData function. In the first one the CPU is idle and in the second the CPU is busy. Clearly when CPU is busy the JS runtime is not asynchronous.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I believe your examples do not illustrate the point. In your first example, your code (`getData()`) does not wait for 3 seconds, it sets an asynchronous timer and **returns back** to the event loop (if called by the event-loop), *not taking any time*. In your second scenario, the callback function is called synchronously by the `getData()` event handler (not really an event callback).

Comment: My point is a) code runs on the event thread and if a callback (or a funcion) is called from that event handler, it will run *synchronously* on same thread. b) but code that is set to run upon an external or internal event will be run asynchronously, upon the event processing (and by the event thread that handles the event) [asynchronously because the event is asynchronous.... but synchronously to the processing of the event]

Answer (score 1):

The main thread of Node is the JS event loop, so all logic interacting with JS is single threaded. This also includes any C++ logic triggered directly via JS.

Generally any long-running tasks should be split off into worker processes. For instance, in your case, you could have a worker process that would queue up calculations, emitting events back to the JS thread when they have completed.

So really, it's a question of how you go about your `connected to c++ via addons` code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to refer to the specifics of Node.js as I'm not that familiar with the internal architecture and the possibilities it allows (but I understand it supports multiple worker threads, each representing a different event loop)

In general, if you need to process 100 request/s that take 5 seconds solid CPU time, then there's nothing you can do, except ensuring that you have 500 processors available.

If 100 request/s is peak, while on average it will be much lower, then the solution is queueing, and you use the queue to absorb the blow.

Now things start to get interesting when it is not 5 seconds solid CPU time, but 0.1 CPU time and 4.9 waiting or anything in between. This is the case where asynchronous processing should be used to put all that waiting time to work.

Asynchronous in this case means that:

- All your execution happens in an event loop.
- You **don't wait**, **no sleep**, **no blocking I/O**, just execute or return to the event loop.
- You split your task into non-blocking subtasks, interspeded with (async) events (e.g. with a response) that continue the execution.
- You split your system into a number of event processing services, exchanging requests and responses through asynchronous events and collaborating to provide the overall functionality.

What to do if you have a subsystem you cannot turn into an asynchronous service under the principles above?

The answer is to wrap it with queues (to absorb the requests) + multiple threads (allowing execution of some threads hile other threads are waiting), providing the async events request/response interface expected by rest of the subsystems.

In all cases it is best to keep a bounded number of threads (instead of a per-request thread model) and always keep the total number of *active/hot* threads in the system below the number of processing resources.

Node.js is nice in that its input/output is inherently asynchronously and all the infrastructure is geared towards implementing the kind of things I described above.